# Inovoke a method on the object passed as parameter

Tags: java

How do I invoke a method on an object passed as parameter?
Do I know the object passed?
No
Do all of the possible objects passed have this method?
Yes

This is what I mean:

```
    public void setOwled(Obj character){
    character.getIsOwled() = true;
}
```

`getIsOwled()` is the common method, and `character` is the `object` passed as parameter.

```
setOwled()
```

is a method of just 1 class, which should change a `mVariable` of the object passed as parameter.

Comment: You need the type of the object passed in to have the appropriate method, and you can't assign to the result of a method; you can never write anything like `foo.bar() = baz`.

Comment: Is there a corresponding `setOwled` method on `Obj`?

Comment: Nope @Makoto setOwled is a method of just 1 class, which should change a mVariable of the object passed as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix up method invocation and Attribute Setting.

I think you mean something like this:

```
 class myObject1 {
    public String myName = "";
    // constructor - no return value
    public myObject1 (String aName) {
        this.myName = aName;
    }

    public void printMyName() {
        System.out.println("Object 1: My Name is: " + this.myName);
    }
}

class myObject2 {
    public String myName = "";
    // constructor - no return value
    public myObject2 (String aName) {
        this.myName = aName;
    }

    public void printMyName() {
        System.out.println("Object 2: My Name is: " + this.myName);
    }
}


class runClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object [] elements = new Object[2];
        elements[0] = new myObject1("Jon Doe");
        elements[1] = new myObject2("Mr. Smith");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            runClass.workOnElement(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void workOnElement (Object theElem) {
      if (theElem instanceof myObject1) {
        myObject1 elem = (myObject1) theElem;
        elem.printMyName();
      } else if (theElem instanceof myObject2) {
        myObject2 elem = (myObject2) theElem;
        elem.printMyName();
      }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Object 1: My Name is Jon Doe
Object 2: My Name is Mr. Smith
```

Comment: Yes, you're almost there, the fact is I've more than 1 object, like myObject1, myObject2 etc

Comment: Just a note, I very much recommend the class names starting capitalized in Java.

Comment: Ok, got it. I updated my answer.  `instanceof` and casting is your friend here...

Comment: Yeap instanceof and casting have been my friends ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want but perhaps you will find it useful:

The trick here would be to know exactly what the Object is which was passed as an argument to the method which is going to make the decision as to what will be done with that particular Object once it's received.

Normally, while coding you know exactly what object will be passed to the Method you've created and therefore declare the parameter explicitly to that particular Object Type (such as String, int, double, etc.) but there are indeed times when you want a method to accept a single argument which could be any one of several Object Types. That's the easy part, the more difficult part is knowing exactly what each Object Type is actually Named. Not so difficult for Variable types such as String, Integer, Double, Float, etc...but for more complex Objects such as Controls, Classes, etc. If you have been working with Java for some time now then you're not going to have an issue with this.

Let's create a small method which will determine the Type Name of a particular object passed to it as an argument:

```
public static String objectType(final Object objectVar) {
    try {
        // I like to turn Object Type names to Uppercase
        // so everything returned by this method will be
        // in Uppercase.
        return objectVar.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
         System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + 
             "objectType() Method Exception - Unknown Object Type!" + 
             "\u001B[31m");
         return ""; 
    }
}
```

Now your method of which we may need to use this new objectType() method:

```
public void setOwled(Object argument){
    switch (objectType(argument)) {
        case "STRING":
            System.out.println("argument contains a String object type - " + argument.toString());
            break;
        case "INTEGER":
            System.out.println("argument contains a Integer object type - " + (int) argument);
            break;
        case "DOUBLE":
            System.out.println("argument contains a Double object type - " + (double) argument);
            break; 
        case "BOOLEAN":
            System.out.println("argument contains a Boolean object type - " + (boolean) argument);
            break;  
        case "JBUTTON":
            System.out.println("argument holds reference to a JButton object - " + argument);
            break;
    }
}
```

There are obviously lots of Object Type names but you only need to worry about the one's you want to specifically deal with within for your particular Method.

I hope you have found this useful if not at least...entertaining.

Comment: As much as I can see where you're coming from on this, this pretty much negates the use of an object oriented language.  Even so, the `instanceof` operator would be a much more suitable solution

Comment: Hey, it should work the same with my own custom Classes right?